# как сделать присвоение элемента вектора?

Tags: c++, qt

Создал я структуру которую заполнял, после заполнения отправлял в "чужую " функцию (не я её написал и она предоставлена отдельной компанией).

```
typedef struct tagTPCANMsg
{
    DWORD             ID;      // 11/29-bit message identifier
//    TPCANMessageType  MSGTYPE; // Type of the message
    BYTE              MSGTYPE; // Type of the message
    BYTE              LEN;     // Data Length Code of the message (0..8)
    BYTE              DATA[8]; // Data of the message (DATA[0]..DATA[7])
} TPCANMsg;
```

---

```
TPCANMsg trcanmsg;
```

---

```
result = CAN_Write(PCAN_USBBUS1,&trcanmsg); // всё ок
```

Но структуры мне оказалось мало и потребовался вектор структур, был добавлен вектор

```
QVector <TPCANMsg> vector_trcanmsg;  // задаём вектор в который складываем структуру
```

---

```
         result = CAN_Write(PCAN_USBBUS1,&vector_trcanmsg.at(i)); // всё не ок :(
```

Пишет "ошибка: invalid conversion from 'const tagTPCANMsg*' to 'TPCANMsg* {aka tagTPCANMsg*}' [-fpermissive]
              result = CAN_Write(PCAN_USBBUS1,&vector_trcanmsg.at(i));
                                                                    ^
"

Не знаю как правильно преобразовать,  пытался через *(звездочку) но тоже выдаёт ошибку :

```
  result = CAN_Write(PCAN_USBBUS1,*vector_trcanmsg.at(i)); // ошибка
```

Comment: Просто `vector.at(i);`.

Comment: я бы попробовал сделать вектор константным

Comment: @MrBin  `ошибка: cannot convert 'const tagTPCANMsg' to 'TPCANMsg* {aka tagTPCANMsg*}' for argument '2' to 'DWORD CAN_Write(BYTE, TPCANMsg*)'
              result = CAN_Write(PCAN_USBBUS1,vector_trcanmsg.at(i));
                                                                   ^`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan можете пожалуйста написать в виде кода, а то я не совсем понимаю смысл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `at` возвращает константную ссылку, а вам нужна модификация. Тогда используйте `operator[]`.

Comment: `ошибка: expected type-specifier before '[' token
              result = CAN_Write(PCAN_USBBUS1, &vector_trcanmsg.operator [i] );
                                                                         ^`

Comment: слово `.operator` уберите

Comment: `result = CAN_Write(PCAN_USBBUS1, &vector_trcanmsg[i] ); //  собралось :3`